# Unable to call android webview function from angular 7 app

Tags: javascript, android, angular

I am running angular 7 app inside android webview and trying to call a android function to get some data from app.

Let suppose the name of android webview is `android_webview` and there is a function defined in android by the name of `getuserdata`.

This is the code i am using to call android function `android_webview.getUserData()` but for angular 7 `android_webview` is an undefined variable and its showing error and also not letting me use `ng build`.

Is there any specific way to call android webview function in my angular 7 application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on this.

I previously tried it by using `window.android_webview` but i was getting this error `Property 'android_webview' does not exist on type 'Window'.`.

After a little research i found that i can access android variable like this `window['android_webview']`. Now i can access android webview variable inside my angular 7 app.